# Subparagraph numbering not working after changing to aspect

Tags: formatting, paragraphs

I am facing an issue with \subparagraph numbering.

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}


\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\Alph{paragraph}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}°}

\paragraph{Test}
\subparagraph{Test}
\subparagraph{Test}
\paragraph{Test}
\subparagraph{Test}
\subparagraph{Test}

\end{document}
```

These two commands `\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\Alph{paragraph}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}°}` seem to create the issue: as you can see, my subparagraph is following paragraph's numbering. Without it, everything works fine.

[image]

Does anyone know how to format \paragraph and \subparagraph as I wanted without this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why iy doesn't work for \subparagraph, but here is a workaround with `xpatch`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\Alph{paragraph}}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\thesubparagraph}{%
\theparagraph.\@arabic\c@subparagraph}{%
\arabic{subparagraph}\textsuperscript{o}}{}{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Test}
\subparagraph{Test}
\subparagraph{Test}
\paragraph{Test}
\subparagraph{Test}
\subparagraph{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you again @Bernard !